# Is there a library that implements a fast maximum rank correlation estimator?

Tags: python, r, max, rank, correlation

I'm looking for an implementation of a fast maximum rank correlation (MRC) estimator. This will be applied to large-ish sparse matrices (~100,000 by 10,000) in a text-mining application.

I'm working in python and R, so it would be nice to find something in those languages.  Failing that, I could probably convert code from some other language.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for crossvalidated.com

Comment: I've just [cross posted it there](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/is-there-a-library-that-implements-a-fast-maximum-rank-correlation-estimator) b/c I wasn't sure which community was the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Having read up on the subject, MRC estimators are famously hard to compute, although there is [hope](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDEQFjAC&url=http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0165176598002559&ei=9XDNTvnlEcjo2QW_ouW0Dw&usg=AFQjCNE_x7kmesn8SVEwyDfVHJ4tsPOfAw) that maybe better algorithms could be designed.

I'll post this answer to CV as well.